# Junit Test cases for Save and Update using Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've written a Test case to save & update which as below,

```
@InjectMocks
UserController uc;

@Mock
UserService userService;
@Mock
User user;

@Test
public void saveUser() throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:s+ss");
    
    Long id= 2L;
    String userName = "John";
    String passWord = "john";
    Date otpSentDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    Date createdDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    Date updatedDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    user.setId(id);user.setUserName(userName);user.setPassWord(passWord);user.setOtpSentDate(otpSentDate);
    user.setCreatedDate(createdDate);user.setUpdatedDate(updatedDate);
    assertEquals(1, uc.saveUser(user));
}

@Test
public void updateUser() throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:s+ss");
    
    Long id= 2L;
    String userName = "John";
    String passWord = "john";
    Date otpSentDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    Date createdDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    Date updatedDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    user.setId(id);user.setUserName(userName);user.setPassWord(passWord);user.setOtpSentDate(otpSentDate);
    user.setCreatedDate(createdDate);user.setUpdatedDate(updatedDate);
    assertEquals(1, uc.updateUser(user));
}
```

Controller for both methods are as below,

```
 @PostMapping("/saveUser")
public int saveUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    if (user.getUserName() == "" || user.getPassWord() == "") {
        throw new Exception("User name or Password should not be empty!");
    } else {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        System.out.println("Inserted data with id: "+ user.getId());
    }
    return 1;
}
@PutMapping("/updateUser")
public void updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.updateUser(user);
    System.out.println("User with id "+ user.getId() + " updated successfully!");
}
```

And ServiceImpl.java are as follows,

```
@Override
public void saveUser(User user) {
    userMapper.saveUser(user);
}
 @Override
public void updateUser(User user) {
    userMapper.updateUser(user);
}
```

After running above methods, I'm getting error as below,
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.naveen.MybatisApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'user'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.naveen.entity.User' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: Generally the issue is raised if anyone of the autowired dependencies are not mocked in test class. Please check if all the DI present in actual code are mocked or available in test code. Also check this `@Autowired User user;` is `User` a bean or not? If not, remove autowiring.

Comment: @LUC1F3R Now, after changing Autowired annotation to Mock annotation, the test case passed, but data is not inserted in DB. Could you please check the above code?

Comment: Yes, because you have mocked your service. So anything that is to be executed by your service is mocked i.e. no actual execution will be done for it. Also, what you're doing is unit testing i.e. at a time only single component is tested: controller, service, dao (repo). If you want to test your actual code from end to end, you need to write integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

You test logic is wrong (:

You have userService as a Mock object - it won't return anything if you don't write it by yourself. And it won't save in the db anything. You can just verify calling this Mock:

```
then(userService).should(times(1)).saveUser(any(User.class));
```

And you don't need these rows:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:s+ss");
    
    Long id= 2L;
    String userName = "John";
    String passWord = "john";
    Date otpSentDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    Date createdDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    Date updatedDate = simpleformat.parse("2019-12-24 01:22:05+00");
    user.setId(id);user.setUserName(userName);user.setPassWord(passWord);user.setOtpSentDate(otpSentDate);
    user.setCreatedDate(createdDate);user.setUpdatedDate(updatedDate);
```

because user is also a Mock object.

So your test will be something like that:

```
@Test
public void saveUser() throws Exception {
//given
     given(user.getUserName()).willReturn("Username");
     given(user.getPassWord()).willReturn("Password");
     given(user.getId()).willReturn(1);
     given(userService.saveUser(any(User.class))).willReturn(user);
//when
     int result = uc.saveUser(user);
//then
     then(userService).should(times(1)).saveUser(any(User.class));
     assertEquals(1, result);
}
```

Comment: Here given with user given(user.getUserName()) is not getting imported. But, given with userService got imported. Any idea?

Comment: @Naveen check your imports for User class or delete '@'Mock User user and write: User user = new User(); user.setId(1L); user.setUserName("Username"); user.setPassWord("Password");  in //given section instead  given(user.getUserName()).willReturn("Username");
     given(user.getPassWord()).willReturn("Password");
     given(user.getId()).willReturn(1);

Comment: Still I'm getting an error "The method given(String) is undefined for the type MybatisApplicationTests"